# Node.js server.listening flag always false

Tags: node.js

**READ BELOW FOR ACTUAL EXPLANATION**

I expect `listening` to return `true` while... well... listening. Instead, I get `false` despite documentation stating otherwise. Nobody made a bug report and nobody had that problem, so... it's me! Isn't it?

What's wrong with this code?

```js
"use strict";

const mod_net = require("net");
const server = mod_net.createServer((socket) => { /* ignore */ });

console.log(`BEFORE: ${server.listening}`);

server.listen(8000, "127.0.0.1");

console.log(`AFTER: ${server.listening}`);
```

The output is:

```sh
> BEFORE: false
> AFTER: false
```

**ACTUAL EXPLANATION**

The codebase is rather large, I tried to reduce per SO policy to minimal code, but for fun let's look at a better example of how I messed up my own test.

What I wanted is test if a cleanup function would properly do it's work, so I threw an intentional `throw` between the lines and expected the cleanup function to fire.

```js
"use strict";

const mod_net = require("net");
const server = mod_net.createServer((socket) => { /* ignore */ });

process.on("exit", () => {

  console.log(`IN EXIT: ${server.listening}`);

  if (server.listening)
  {
    server.close();

    console.log("SEND BYE-BYE MESSAGE AND 'FIN' TO SOCKETS");
  }

  console.log("GRACEFUL SHUTDOWN");
});

server.listen(8000, "127.0.0.1");

throw new Error("Boom!");
```

The output is:

```sh
IN EXIT: false
GRACEFUL SHUTDOWN
/home/pid/dev/test.js:26
throw new Error("Boom!");
^
```

As you can see, `server.listener` is still `false`. And that's the **EXPECTED CORRECT** behaviour of node.js because as shown in the answer by @AKX it's async. The `server.listen()` never had a chance to run, because the `throw` broke control flow before time.

What is really wrong here, is the attempt to simulate an async exception by writing it there!

Sadly for me, this attempt is not representative of the actual bug I'm encountering in the full codebase.

Comment: FWIW it looks like you are trying to re-implement what's already implemented in node.js tcp module. On exit all sockets are closed automatically and the other side will not be left with a half-open socket.

Comment: I know it looks like it, truth is on intentional shutdown an orchestrator will spawn another node. The "bye-bye" message is a complex protobuf message that contains IP:port of a new node that will take over, so client connectors should reconnect to the new pod. Sorry for going too much into details here but you asked for it ;-P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`server.listen` is asynchronous. Try

```
server.listen(8000, "127.0.0.1", () => {
    console.log(`AFTER: ${server.listening}`); 
}) ;
```